# Caliburn Micro Conductor + TransitioningContentControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, caliburn.micro

I'm having an issue getting my CM Conductor maintaining a proper binding of Active to the contents of a TransitioningContentControl.

In case it matters, I am using a `Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive`

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

Create a TransitioningContentControl bound to the conductors ActiveItem:

```
<toolkit:TransitioningContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
```

Create two buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="Nav1" Content="Test1"></Button>
<Button x:Name="Nav2" Content="Test2"></Button>
```

In the view model, wire up the Nav1 and Nav2 click events to set the activeitem

```
public void Nav1()
{
    ActiveItem = _viewModel1;
}

public void Nav2()
{
    ActiveItem = _viewModel2;
}
```

At first glance, this appears to work fine - however there's a problem.   Let's say the active item represents Nav1 (_viewModel1).

If you then click Nav2, and click Nav1 before the transitioniningContentControl is finished with the transition, the view for Nav2 will still be displayed on the screen even though ActiveItem will successfully be set back to _viewModel1.

This puts you in an invalid state where ActiveItem is _viewModel1, but the view being displayed is bound that for _viewModel2.

Ideas?   Is there something wrong about binding to ActiveItem directly?

Edit:

After turning off "Just my code" debugging, I see that there is an ArgumentException being thrown when setting ActiveItem during the transition.  Stack trace shows:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
(lots of junk)
Caliburn.Micro!Caliburn.Micro.View.SetContentPropertyCore(object targetLocation, object view) + 0xec bytes  
Caliburn.Micro!Caliburn.Micro.View.SetContentProperty(object targetLocation, object view) + 0x84 bytes  
Caliburn.Micro!Caliburn.Micro.View.OnModelChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject targetLocation, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) + 0xda bytes
```

Not sure if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try the Conductors ActivateItem method instead to stet the ActiveItem property.

```
public void Nav1()
{
    ActiveItem(_viewModel1);
}
```

I hope this will help

Martin

Comment: Doesn't matter.  ActiveItem setter just turns around and calls ActivateItem anyways:  public T ActiveItem {
            get { return activeItem; }
            set { ActivateItem(value); }
        }